# Release static reference on Android Fragment

Tags: android

I declare an static Fragment variable in onCreateView like this:

```
public static Fragment instance;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
instance = this;
}
```

I understand this will cause memory leak so I need to release the instance variable properly (instance=null). Just wonder where I should release it. Like inside onPause or onDestroyView or other overriding method?

Comment: It is not static reference if you don't use the word "static" in variable declaration.  Not sure what you are asking?  Normal member variables will be garbage collected when the enclosing Fragment object is destroyed

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the static in front. Edit my question.

Comment: Okay, now can you explain why you need a static reference to Fragment in your code?

Comment: Probably he needs it to access methods. Its nasty way to do it, if so.

Comment: Yeah, it is nasty way, and to my surprise, it seems to be quite prevalent among Android developers.

Comment: Well I need to get the instance of running fragment for my push notification to update the UI. So far I can't find a better to perform such task, so...

Comment: Rather than nasty, it's not what the Android pattern suggests. The idea is to have a static method in your fragments that does this: public static SomeFragment newInstance(Context context) {
  sContext = context.getApplicationContext();
  return new SomeFragment();
 } ---this way you have a static reference to the app context (in case you need to launch activities or anything else) and you have a common way to initialize your fragments. The Android Source code does this a lot and I've done it myself.

Comment: yeah that way you can have the app context, but how about calling a method in that activity from outside, context doesn't have any references to that I suppose.

Comment: I've just written the same code in a fragment (static reference, set it to "this" in onCreate(), set it to null in onDestroy()), and now I'm wondering if I've done a bad thing. Did you keep this code in your app? Has it caused any problems that you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this [Fragment life cycle](http://docs.xamarin.com/static/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/Images/fragment_lifecycle.png) you may see that the last method that is called before the Fragment is completely done with it existence is the `onDetach()` method, you may want to release all the resources here, since it ensures that the fragment is finishing forever and can not cause any problems with resuming, restarting etc.

Comment: Is there any problem if I release the resource in onDestroyView?

Comment: I cannot say. It depends on your implementations that depend on Fragment's life. Check it by yourself.